# Boolean value set to false in plist is coming out as true

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a boolean in a plist as so:

[image]

Which when viewed as source looks like:

[image]

And its read as:

```
 NSDictionary* configPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Config" ofType:@"plist"];
  BOOL shouldBeFalse = configPlist[@"WhyIsThisReturningTrue"];
```

But when the code is read shouldBeFalse is YES.

In the debugger configPlist's value for this is NO:[image]

Why therefore is shouldBeFalse getting set to YES when the code is run?

Comment: Don't you get a warning *Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'BOOL'...*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you refer to the `NSNumber` pointer, not the value. It is somewhat similar to doing

```
    NSNumber * b = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

    if ( b )
    {
        NSLog(@"This should fire, b is not nil" );
    }
    if ( b.boolValue )
    {
        NSLog(@"This should NOT fire, b's value is NO" );
    }
```

So just change it to e.g. `[configPlist[@"WhyIsThisReturningTrue"] boolValue]`